# Landscape application Bar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need the application bar in landscape view when windows phone is in landscape mode(like IE). Because when in the landscape mode, the application bar is in the right or left side so some of my contents(links) are not visible(link). Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/100703/598355.aspx) there no possible solution with native application bar. But you can use some third-party controls like [this](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

Here the idea: you can put your RoundButtons provided by Coding4Fun toolkit into a separate Grid. And then attach this Grid to the bottom of your XAML page. In such case you will emulate Application Bar.

Comment: But how IE has it? Then we don't have that permissions,right?

Comment: It's not about IE, it's about whole XAML page :). E.g. look at this markup:

`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
 <StackPanel>
  <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <SomePanelWithRoundButtons>
                 ...
             </SomePanelWithRoundButtons>
        </StackPanel>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>`

Where `SomePanelWithRoundButtons` is a some panel that mimics ApplicationBar with it's RoundButtons. So it will be detached from WebBrowser component. Sorry, but stackoverflow editor ate my formatting :(